# Cocos2d: Adding a CCSequence to a CCArray

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, objective-c

I have a problem with an action performed by a sprite. I have one CCSequence in a CCArray and I have an scheduled method (is called every 5 seconds) that make the sprite run the action. The action is performed correctly only the first time (the first 5 seconds), after that, it does not.

Here is the code:

In .h ->

```
@interface PowerUpLayer : CCLayer {
    PowerUp *powerUp;
    CCArray *trajectories;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCArray *trajectories;
```

In .mm ->

```
@implementation PowerUpLayer

@synthesize trajectories;

-(id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        [self createTrajectories];
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        [self schedule:@selector(spawn:) interval:5];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)createTrajectories
{
    self.trajectories = [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

    //Wave trajectory
    ccBezierConfig firstWave, secondWave;

    firstWave.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width + 30, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);//powerUp.sprite.position.x, powerUp.sprite.position.y);
    firstWave.controlPoint_2 = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width / 4), 0);
    firstWave.endPosition = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width / 2, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);

    secondWave.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width / 2, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);
    secondWave.controlPoint_2 = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width / 4, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height);

    secondWave.endPosition = CGPointMake(-30, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);

    id bezierWave1 = [CCBezierTo actionWithDuration:1 bezier:firstWave];
    id bezierWave2 = [CCBezierTo actionWithDuration:1 bezier:secondWave];

    id waveTrajectory = [CCSequence actions:bezierWave1, bezierWave2, [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)], nil];

    [self.trajectories addObject:waveTrajectory];
    //[powerUp.sprite runAction:bezierForward];

    //        [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:3 position:CGPointMake(-[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - powerUp.sprite.contentSize.width, 0)]
    //[powerUp.sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:bezierWave1, bezierWave2, [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)], nil]];

}

-(void)setInvisible:(id)sender
{
    if(powerUp != nil)
    {
        [self removeChild:sender cleanup:YES];
        powerUp = nil;
    }
}
```

This is the scheduled method:

```
-(void)spawn:(ccTime)dt
{
    if(powerUp == nil)
    {
        powerUp = [[PowerUp alloc] initWithType:0];

        powerUp.sprite.position = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width + powerUp.sprite.contentSize.width, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);

        [self addChild:powerUp.sprite z:-1];

        [powerUp.sprite runAction:((CCSequence *)[self.trajectories objectAtIndex:0])];
    }
}
```

I don't know what is happening; I never modify the content of the CCSequence after the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely copy and autorelease the action everytime you execute it, so that it doesn't get consumed.

Yes, a `CCAction` can't be used twice without duplicating it. Try with:

```
[powerUp.sprite runAction:((CCSequence *)[[[self.trajectories objectAtIndex:0] copy] autorelease])];
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I've tested it and it works! How safe is this solution? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely safe, if you check `CCAction` implementations you see that `init` is used to duplicate the action. That's why `copy` will actually (as usually) increase the retain count and that's finally why you need to `autorelease` it. Even because it will be retained again by adding it as a running action of the `CCNode`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `CCAction` classes are designed to run only once. You cannot re-use them.

The only way I'm aware of is to call the `init` method (eg. `initWithDuration`) of the action again, but this is bad practice, because `init` should only be called once after construction of the object and might lead to memory-leaks or other issues if called multiple times.

In your case I suggest you modify your `createTrajectories` function to build and return a new `CCSequence` every time (so simply return `waveTrajectory` instead of adding it to the array). Then in your `spawn` function, you could do something like:

```
[powerUp.sprite runAction:[self createTrajectories]];
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. That's indeed a good solution. What do you think about the solution given by Jack?

Comment: @Axort I think they are about equal. Both will allocate a new object. Personally I would rather use my proposal, because I think it is more readable and understandable where stuff gets allocated etc.